# Could you change the Balloon msg for [ You really want to cancel your upvote ? ]

Tags: feature-request, voting, up-votes, bookmarks

( I suspect ... maybe I'm wondering about this only because of my browser setting. )

When I put my cursor over the [Upvote] button, a balloon msg appears, which says:

```
      This question shows ...  ..... (click again to undo)
```

<strike>So I never know if I've upvoted it already.</strike>

I see, the  (click again to undo) appears only because I upvoted it already.

I wish it said this instead:

> You've already upvoted .... hours ago (click again to undo your upvote)

The same thing happens for the [This is my fav. question.] button.

Actually, for the [my favorite question] button, the same "(click to undo)" message appears in the balloon BEFORE and AFTER an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Although the actual icons used vary from site to site, it should be evident from the up/down/favourite icons being more solid.

For example, on the question below I have already set the question to be a favourite and upvoted it.  The downvote icon has the more faded look that indicates I have not done that.

[image]